# How do I remove only certain words (not lines containing that word) from a text file with a Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a batch file that uses an output from a dir command to perform other tasks, I also want to use this same output (stored in dir_output.txt) for another use, but I don't want the file extensions at the end. right now the file looks like this:

```
barrier_1_post.p3d 
barrier_1_section.p3d
```

but I want it to look like this

```
barrier_1_post 
barrier_1_section
```

minus the file extensions, but I have no idea how to do this via the batch, I've looked through SO exhaustively but either I'm not finding the solution or I can't see the wood for the trees.

Any help would be amazing, I'm fairly new to batches.

Comment: Honestly, unless you're using a very old version of Windows, you should ditch `cmd` and instead embrace `powershell`. It is _so_ much better, it even gives `bash` a run for its money :-)

Comment: Magoo gave a pretty simple solution, but to clarify why I am reluctant to use powershell:  this batch will be distributed and used by others in my team, so I want to avoid situations where they would need anything additional to the batch file, though I will look at powershell for myself, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (yourfilename.txt) do echo %%~na
```

should remove those extensions quite happily.

`%~na` delivers the name part only of the assumed filename in `%a`

(see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation)

Comment: Thank you Magoo that worked perfectly for me, and my larger batch now does exactly what I need it to

Comment: You should [**accept**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this as the answer.